# Multiple case expressions

Tags: ruby

I have two variables `field1` and `field2`. I need to do a `case` statement on each variable:

```
case field1
when "val1"
  puts field1
when "val2"
  puts field2
end

case field2
when "val1"
  puts field1
when "val2"
  puts field2
end
```

How can I implement something like the above in a single `case` statement? Something like this:

```
case field1, field2
when "val1"
  puts field1
when "val2"
  puts field2
end
```

Will any monkey patching help?

Comment: Wrap it in a loop: `[field1, field2].each { |f| case f ... }`

Comment: Or place your case inside a method and call it for each field.

Comment: Does `[field1, field2]` equal `['val1', 'val2']` or `['val2', 'val1']`? If so, `['val1', 'val2'].tap { |a| a.reverse! if field1 == 'val2' }.each { |v| puts v }`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unclear what field 1 and 2 can contain. You could to a switch statement on an array of two elements.

```
  case [field1, field2]
  when [1,1]
    puts "a"
  when [1,2]
    puts "b"
  else
    puts "I got nothing"
  end
```

But does probably rarely is a good idea, so you could also just do elseif, so you can check for any conditions that are to be handled

```
if field1 == field2
   puts "Impossible!"
elsif field1.length > field2.length
   puts "Something"
elsif [field1, field2].any?(&:nil?)
   puts "I need two fields there, my friend"
else
   puts "I am disappointed"
end
```